# What are the available credit card companies that offer virtual credit card number generation?

Tags: security, virtual-credit-card

What credit card companies offer virtual credit card number generation for one-time purchases for extra security over the Internet?

I heard that PayPal offers this for their debut card, but am not sure it is still offered.

I also heard that Citibank and Bank of America offer it.

Please confirm with actual recent experiences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, citibank allows you to create [virtual credit card number](https://www.citibank.com/us/cards/vanpromo/cmc_pop/index2.htm). I use it a few times a year when buy something from abroad. It's actually not a one time but rather one number per merchant. Once you use it (let's say at amazon) you can keep using it at amazon until it expires. You set the limit and the expiration months.

Comment: fiacardservices.com does this too. I love using it for those sneaky "pay $1 now" in big letters with "we will your card $100/month from then on".